# Microsoft Visual Studio returns different results than running executable via command line

Tags: visual-studio, cplex

I am currently running a program that uses CPLEX concert technology in release mode using Visual Studio (Ctrl + F5), and then I've run the executable via the command line as well.

I am getting repeatable results, but the two different methods return different values. Moreover, the two different methods produce different LP files - one has 12 more constraints than the other.

I'm exclusively running in release mode, so I don't believe this is an issue with debug vs. release.

Based on the recommendations in similar questions, I downloaded the [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) (and used default settings) to eliminate any uninitialized variables and shadow errors, etc.

At this point, I'm at a loss for what to do. I have warnings when I compile about not having `concert.pdb` (but I don't think this should be an issue since I'm not debugging) and some "32-big shift implicitly converting to 64 bits" as a result of my `ilcplex/ilocplex.h` include.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it use files for any kind of input, such that the different working directories of the two methods would see different files?

Comment: Yes, it reads through an input file, and the two methods do run from different directories, but I have confirmed the input file is exactly the same for both (copied and pasted from one directory to another).

Answer (score 1):

It will be in your code or how you are running it, so its not really a CPLEX issue. Have you set any command-line arguments for debugging in Visual Studio? Are you sure you are running in the same folder, with the same data etc?

If its not anything obvious, these differences are usually due to things like uninitialsed variables or similar, even if you have already checked for that.

Presumably you are looping over sets of data to build your model, so try an old-school approach and write some text to the console or a log file at key points in your code, such as before each loop, and inside each loop, and again at the end. Try simple counting how many of each sort of constraint you are generating in the code, and put that in your logging too.

Also, it is useful to name your variables and constraints in a rational way so that the contents of the LP files makes sense to you, then you should be able to see which constraints are added/missing/different. Use names that make sense to you, like "Site_1_Time_1", "Site_2_Time_1" and so on, it is them much easier to read than stupid short names like "xij", or the default built-in naming.

In virtually every real-world system I have written, I do both - write a log file so I can see what happened and why, and I set the names of all the variables and constraints in my models. Both of these techniques have saved me days of time tracking down errors.

Comment: No command-line arguments, but the methods do run in different folders. However, they use the same input file (copied and pasted from one directory to another).

Thanks for your advice - I will add the log files and re-name my constraints to get a clearer idea of what's happening.